# Interpolate variable into HTTParty POST Call

Tags: ruby, httparty

I am trying to send a post request to a Pardot Api based on the values from a csv file. I can read the csv values and assign them to variables (id and list) but when I try and do a HTTParty post and slot the variables into the post request I get an error:

> URI must be ascii only
>   "https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/update/id/\uFEFF114337534?list_179174=1&api_key=a19876543211234567&user_key=a12345678987654321"
>   (URI::InvalidURIError)

Here is the full script I am running. I have swapped out the key values but you can see the interpolated variables in the url string. From the error it looks like the list variable is getting inserted but not the id variable.

**Full Code**

```
require 'csv'

require 'rubygems'

require 'httparty'


CSV.foreach('update_of_lists.csv') do |row|

  id = row[0]

  list = row[1]


HTTParty.post("https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/update/id/#{id}?list_#{list}=1&api_key=a1234567890&user_key=a1234543212345a")



end
```

Comment: The problem is your `id` is a non-asci variable. can you post the content of the `update_of_lists.csv`

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your reply. I saved the document again as a basic .csv file. The first time I had saved it as a .csv with UTF-8 which seemed to be the cause.